# whats going on in this script

Tags: javascript, properties, scope, scoping

I am sorry i cant be very specific to metion what is going on with the script. 
I wrote this piece of script to understand property modification in the javascripit. I have a variable `ctx` and it has two properties `ctx.exports` and `ctx.module.exports`. As you can see int eh code below, i have establised the relation `ctx.module.exports = ctx.exports`
so when `ctx.exports` gets modified `ctx.module.exports` holds the same value.
but the script below suggests otherwise.

```js
var ctx = {};
ctx.exports = {};
ctx.module = {
  exports: ctx.exports
}

ctx.exports = {
  h: "hello"
}


if (ctx.exports == ctx.module.exports) {
  console.log("hi");
} else {
  console.log("hey");
}
```

however when i store the `ctx.exports` value to a local variable `exports` in this case. `exports` becomes equal with `ctx.module.exports` on modification of `ctx.exports`

```js
var ctx = {};
ctx.exports = {};
ctx.module = {
  exports: ctx.exports
}

var exports = ctx.exports;
ctx.exports = {
  h: "hello"
}


if (exports == ctx.module.exports) {
  console.log("hi");
} else {
  console.log("hey");
}
```

cn anybody explain me what is happening in this case? is this a type of scoping in java script. does this have a proper name?

## edit

as expllained by the first answer the `ctx.module.exports` is checking against `{}` that is why it is a match. but in that case, why is this failing

```js
var ctx = {};
ctx.exports = {};
ctx.module = {
  exports: ctx.exports
}

var exports = ctx.exports;
ctx.exports = {
  h: "hello"
}

if ({} == ctx.module.exports) {
  console.log("hi");
} else {
  console.log("hey");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at what is being compared.  In the first example, you set `ctx.module.exports` to reference `ctx.exports`, which was an empty object: `{}`.  Then you overwrote `ctx.exports` with a new value: `{ h: "hello" }`.  `ctx.module.exports` maintained its reference to the original object, while `ctx.exports` now referenced a different object: you're comparing `{}` against `{ h: "hello" }`.

In the second example, you're again overwriting `ctx.exports` with a new object, but you are comparing two references to the original object: `{}` to `{}`.  It's a match.

EDIT - for a little more clarity
When you set the value of a variable, you are linking a name to a reference.  Overwriting that variable creates a new reference with the same name, but does not modify the reference, which is why overwriting `ctx.exports` had no effect upon either other reference.

**EDIT RESPONSE TO QUESTION EDIT**
You can't compare objects like that.  `{} !== {}` because each object literal declaration creates a new Object instance.  The reason your references can be compared is because they are references to the same object, i.e., the one created by `ctx.exports = {}`.

**MORE EDITS!**
You can see this in effect by comparing the JSON value of each object: `JSON.stringify({}) == JSON.stringify(ctx.module.exports)` is true because it's comparing identical strings; `{} == ctx.module.exports` is false because it is comparing different objects, albeit two objects constructively identical.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not with the comparison, but with the assignments:

```
ctx.module = {
  exports: ctx.exports
}
```

This creates a "link" of `ctx.exports` to `ctx.module.exports`, as the object itself is not duplicated, but only it's reference assigned to `ctx.module.exports`.

But after assigning

```
ctx.exports = {
  h: "hello"
}
```

one part of the link is overwritten.

If you wanted to add a new value to the `sys.exports` without destroying the link, you could use this:

```
ctx.exports.h = "hello";
```